# Can I integrate Tableau in .Net code

Tags: .net, tableau-api

I'm writing a code in .net and I saw Tableau which is pretty impressive so can I integrate it in my code

Comment: Looking at the tags of your question, did you actually mean tableau-server or tableau desktop?

Answer (score 0):

It's very unclear what you're trying to achieve but you can expose your data as an Odata service that Tableau can use as a data source.

[More info on building an OData service based on WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: I'm desinging a website which gives the analysis of data given by the user.So is it possible to get tableau on my  website by integrating it  so the user experience the best output

Comment: If you mean embed tableau in your app, the answer is probably no. What you can do is let tableau desktop/server retrieve your data and analyze it.